What would a 3 equation model with no central bank intervtion look like when there is a inflationary shock?
I been trying to figure it out this for college. The idea is that in a 3 equation model central bank intervention is needed via norimal intrest rate adjustments but don't they don't what would it look like I don't know?
Could someone give me a clue
Thanks
